# How can I stop the hose from the pump to the filter from leaking?

Tags: pool

Replaced broken hose from above ground pool pump to filter.  Slip on hose.  Have clamped both ends as tight as possible but both ends still leak.  Not a lot but enough to be annoying.  What else can I do?

Comment: did you make sure the connections were clean and the new hose didn't have any burrs were it was cut?

Comment: If the hose is clamping onto a barbed fitting, make sure there are no cuts or nicks in the barbs. It should also be pretty tough to push on (eg, you often need to use a torch to heat the hose slightly). What type of hose? What type of clamps? Pictures can help a lot.

Comment: with the rigid plastic hoses going onto a tapered barb, you really need to push the hose on pretty tight before you ever clamp it.  It really gets close to water tight just by the force of pushing it up onto the taper.  The clamp mostly just stops it from sliding off.  If the hose is loose when you start tightening the clamp, then it's going to leak, no matter how much you tighten the clamp.